# git checkout HEAD~N isn't going to the commit I expect

Tags: git

I'm seeing behavior where `git checkout HEAD~N` isn't going back N commits in my git history.

If my commit history looks like this

```
git log --oneline -n 5

3ad352f (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop, asdf) commit message
93eeda7 Merged in branch (pull request #224)
911eb78 (origin/sdfa, asdf) Removes txt file
4b9de92 branch1
7a162e3 Merged in branch1 (pull request #223)
```

And I do a `git checkout HEAD~5` it was my understanding that my HEAD should then point to the commit 5 commits ago. However when I run this command I see something like this:

```
$ git checkout HEAD~5

$ git rev-parse HEAD
49569625ffe9bfc13fdd4f1f5baab9a72ef7ca02

$ git rev-list --count `git rev-parse HEAD`..develop
13
```

It appears that I actually checked out a commit 13 commits ago instead of 5 like I expected.

Can anyone explain what is going on, and how I can actually checkout a commit N commits ago?

Comment: What is the meaning of five commits back when there are merges? The way `git` behaves there is actually well-documented as well...

Comment: Your commit history is not linear because of the merge commits. Because of this, you cannot sImply count down the lines shown in the `git log --oneline` . Add the `--graph` flag to see the history tree.

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is to checkout `7a162e3 Merged in branch1 (pull request #223)` :

- the easiest, unambiguous way is to run `git checkout 7a162e3` (you have the sha, use it)
- if you had run `git log --oneline --graph -n 5`, you would probably have seen something like :

```
3ad352f * (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop, asdf) commit message
93eeda7 * Merged in branch (pull request #224)
        |\
911eb78 | * (origin/sdfa, asdf) Removes txt file
4b9de92 | * branch1                                
7a162e3 * Merged in branch1 (pull request #223)
```

(*note*: from the commit messages in your question, I'm not sure I understand the correct history of your repo, do check in your terminal how your commits are related)

If the history was as above, counting the "first parents" from your active commit, you would have computed `HEAD~2` (instead of `HEAD~5`)

---

`<commit>~N` will only follow a sequence of "first parents" starting from `<commit>`, while `git log` or `git log --oneline` without other options will list (in a flat list) commits coming from merged branches, which will "add" to the count of displayed commits.

`git log` or `git rev-list` both have a `--first-parent` option, to also restrict the list of displayed commits to this "first parents" sequence :

```
git log --oneline --first-parent HEAD~5..HEAD  # will list only 5 commits
git rev-list --count --first-parent HEAD~5..HEAD  # will display '5'
```

I also highly recommend to abuse the `--graph` option of `git log`, to make sense of how the commits you see depend on one another :

```
git log --oneline --graph   # you will have a view of what commits are merges,
                            # and what commits come from side branches
```

---

*extra note*

since `HEAD` (which is equivalent to `HEAD~0`) is displayed in `git log`'s output, you also have an "off by one" error in `-n 5` : in the list displayed by `git log -n 5`, you will see at most `HEAD~4`, not `HEAD~5`.

Answer (score 1):

"5 commits ago" means following the parent lineage of the current commit. You cannot simply count the lines in the output of `git log --oneline`.

Comment: Is there a way to checkout the Nth line of my `git log --oneline`  without specifying the specific commit?

Comment: @PeterKapteyn Not that I know of. The nth line is pretty much meaningless. Two consecutive commits could be on entirely different branches and therefore unrelated. Merge commits also complicates the issue. Git creates what is known as a directed acyclic graph to represent the history of changes. It will help to read more about this concept in general to gain a deeper understanding of git.

Comment: @PeterKapteyn Perhaps you want `git reflog` instead of `git log`. `git reflog` shows the state of your repo at each command you executed. You can checkout commits in this history using the `HEAD{n}` syntax without knowing the exact commit.